# From Python httplib to Erlang httpc

Tags: python, erlang, httplib

I want to switch from this code in Python to Erlang:

Python:

```
import httplib

body="<xml>...</xml>"
headers = { \
"Accept" :  "text/*" , \
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)" , \
"Host" : "something.com" , \
"Content-Length" : str( len( body ) ) , \
"Connection" : "Keep-Alive" , \
"Cache-Control" : "no-cache" , \
}
server="something.com"
url="/s.srf"

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(server,443)
conn.request("POST", url, body, headers)
```

-> I have tried this Erlang:

```
Headers=[
        {"Accept","text/*"},
        {"User-Agent","Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"},
        {"Host","something.com"},
        {"Content-Length",string:len(Body)},
        {"Connection","Keep-Alive"},
        {"Cache-Control","no-cache"}
        ].
httpc:request(post,{Server,Headers,[],Body},[],[]).
```

but I don't know where I can put the url "/s.srf", any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The first element in the [`request()` tuple](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#id80257) should be the entire URL, not just the server:

```
Url = "http://" ++ Server ++ "/s.srf",
httpc:request(post,{Url,Headers,[],Body},[],[]).
```

You are also setting the Content-Length value using an integer in the Erlang code. According to the same documentation all values should be string typed:

```
{"Content-Length", integer_to_list(string:len(Body))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include it in `Server`, e.g.

```
Server = "http://something.com/s.srf"
```

Given that, you may want to change the variable name. (And don't forget to include the protocol!).

**Source: [httpc docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#request-5)**